# Groovy: Why the node is returning null

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I wanted to add my json response values to an array. My groovy script,

```
 import groovy.json.*
 def ResponseMessage = '''{
 "Unit": {
    "Screen": [{
        "Profile ": {
            "ID ": 12,
            "Rate ": 0
        },
        "Rate ": 600,
        "Primary ": 1,
        "Audio ": [{
            "Id ": 1,
            "Name ": null
        }],
        "Pre ": 5,
        "Post ": 1
    }]
}
} '''
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

def Screen = json.Unit.Screen
log.info Screen
def array= []
Screen.each { s ->
array.addAll(s.Rate,s.Primary,s.Pre)
log.info "array : " + array  
}
```

Array is returning,
INFO:array : [null, null, null]

Comment: You have spaces in your Json? ie: `"Profile "` <-- at the end

Comment: yes :( after removing spaces manually, I got this error ERROR:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 600, Size: 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the *"create an array, call addAll in a loop"* pattern, try this:

```
def array = Screen.collectMany { s ->
    [s.Rate,s.Primary,s.Pre]
}
```

(Of course, once you've removed the spaces from your JSON keys)

Comment: why it is giving me an error for the null keys @tim_yates :(

Comment: @Geeta can you give an example?  I'm not sure what you mean...  Might be another question?

Comment: No issue that was typo sorry